# MySql-Workbench - Is it possible to have 2 different unrelated diagrams within a single model?

Tags: database-design, mysql-workbench, datamodel

I am creating a data model and want to create two independent diagrams, one diagram should show tables from Schema A and another diagram should show tables from Schema B.
I tried doing it in same model but i see both the schemas in both the diagrams (under catalog).

Now i can create another model to do it, and probably it does not make sense to to do it in same model but just want to check if its possible to do in the same model, if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

The catalog tree will always show all objects from the model. That cannot be separated. But otherwise you can still create one diagram for one isolated aspect and another one for something else. The diagram is the essential part, while the catalog tree, bird's eyes view etc. are just helpers, which are not shown in an eventual image/graphic export (if you choose to do one).